# sql server pivot data without aggregate function and print all values in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

Trying to figure how to write a pivot sql server statement. I have following table

Source Table

```
ID |Product |Event        |Date 
-----------------------------------------------
1  |Laptop  |Search       |2020-07-17 14:41:13.535
1  |Laptop  |Product Page |2020-07-17 14:41:13.535
1  |Laptop  |Bought       |2020-07-17 14:41:13.535
1  |Tablet  |Search       |2020-07-18 14:41:13.535
1  |Tablet  |Product Page |2020-07-18 14:41:13.535
1  |Tablet  |Bought       |2020-07-18 14:41:13.535
```

Desired Output

```
 ID|   Product |Search                  |Product Page             |Bought
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |   Laptop  |2020-07-17 14:41:13.535 |2020-07-17 14:41:13.535  |2020-07-17 14:41:13.535
 1 |   Tablet  |2020-07-18 14:41:13.535 |2020-07-18 14:41:13.535  |2020-07-18 14:41:13.535
```

My Query looks like

```
with V1 as 
(
select id,product,event,start_time_local
from table1
)
select id,product,
[search],[product page],[Bought] from V1
PIVOT (Max(start_time_local) for event_type in ([search],[product page],[Bought]))
as PivotTable;
```

When i take Max(date) it returns with only max value wherein i want to display all dates.

Comment: Pivoting is a form of aggregation, you can't `PIVOT`/Cross tab and *not* aggregate. End of Story.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can't `PIVOT`/Cross Tag *without* aggregating as it is a form of aggregation. Personally, however, I recommend using the latter (also known as conditional aggregation), as it's far less restrictive. Then you can do the following:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       Product,
       MAX(CASE Event WHEN 'Search' THEN Date END) AS Search,
       MAX(CASE Event WHEN 'Product Page' THEN Date END) AS ProductPage,
       MAX(CASE Event WHEN 'BOught' THEN Date END) AS Bough
FROM (VALUES(1,'Laptop','Search      ','2020-07-17T14:41:13.535'),
            (1,'Laptop','Product Page','2020-07-17T14:41:13.535'),
            (1,'Laptop','Bought      ','2020-07-17T14:41:13.535'),
            (1,'Tablet','Search      ','2020-07-18T14:41:13.535'),
            (1,'Tablet','Product Page','2020-07-18T14:41:13.535'),
            (1,'Tablet','Bought      ','2020-07-18T14:41:13.535'))V(ID,Product,Event,Date)
GROUP BY ID,
         Product;
```